# Convert xml to json in Jenkinsfile

Tags: json, xml, jenkins-pipeline

I have a problem with a method in my Jenkinsfile when i tried to convert xml to json. That is the method, and the pipeline.
I tried to pass the method directly to the echo, but it gives me an error and the pipeline fails
Sorry but i don't know that details i could give about the error, because i start to learning and this is the first time that i see this code.

ERROR: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

I edit my question and i add a bat in stage OWASP dependencies testing. This bat create automatically the xml, i put in a validator xml and this did not errors. So i don't know if the problem is with the code of Jenkinsfile or xml, because the error is the same. I put part of xml code because it's very long, but 
the error is still in the second line.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<analysis xmlns="https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check.2.2.xsd">
   <scanInfo>
      <engineVersion>5.2.2</engineVersion>
      <dataSource>
         <name>NVD CVE Checked</name>
         <timestamp>2019-11-25T09:01:51</timestamp>
      </dataSource> 
      <datasource>...</datasource>
   </scanInfo>
   ....................
</analysis>
```

---

```
import groovy.json.*;

 def getDependencyResumeFromXML(pathReport){
        def xml = bat(script:'type ' + pathReport, returnStdout:true);

        def x = new XmlParser().parseText(xml);

        def nDep = x.dependencies.dependency.size();

        def dependencies = [:];

        for(def i=0;i<nDep;i++){


            dependencies[i] = [fileName: x.dependencies.dependency[i].fileName.text(),description:x.dependencies.dependency[i].description.text(),vulnerabilities:[:]];

            def nVul = x.dependencies.dependency[i].vulnerabilities.vulnerability.size();

            for(def j=0;j<nVul;j++){

                dependencies[i].vulnerabilities[j] = [
                 name:x.dependencies.dependency[i].vulnerabilities.vulnerability[j].name.text(),                   cvssScore:x.dependencies.dependency[i].vulnerabilities.vulnerability[j].cvssScore.text(),
                   severity:x.dependencies.dependency[i].vulnerabilities.vulnerability[j].severity.text(),

                  cwe:x.dependencies.dependency[i].vulnerabilities.vulnerability[j].cwe.text(),
                  description:x.dependencies.dependency[i].vulnerabilities.vulnerability[j].description.text(),

                ];

            }

        }

        return dependencies;
    }

pipeline{
.......

  stages{
    stage('OWASP dependencies testing'){ 
                    steps{
                        script{
                      bat 'mvn org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:check';

                            def pathReport = 'C:\\tmp\\workspace\\umbrella-pipeline-prueba\\target\\dependency-check\\dependency-check-report.xml';

                            def xml = bat(script:'type ' + pathReport, returnStdout:true);

                            echo '------------------ 1';
                            echo xml;
                            echo '------------------ 2';

                            echo '--------------------------------'

                            def dependencias = getDependencyResumeFromXML(pathReport);

                            echo '------------- 3';
                            echo dependencias;
                            echo '------------- 4';                      
                        }
                    }
                }
}
}
```

Comment: The error from the XML parser is the clue: "Content is not allowed in prolog". This is saying that the XML passed to the script _appears_ to be badly-formed (i.e. not valid XML). You should start by opening the XML file in a web browser - if it fails with the same error then fix the XML file.

Comment: I edit my question because i think it's neccesary the xml code @Kimbert

Comment: The XML _looks_ OK, but that does not mean that it is a well-formed document _when presented to the Jenkins XML parser_. Sometimes that XML parsing error is produced when the character encoding of the XML doc is incorrect (e.g. UTF-16 instead of UTF-8).